# How can I return a new instance of a class as a string and use it as a parameter of a generic method?

Tags: c#, fizzbuzz

I have this generic method to solve the fizzbuzz quiz but when I use the class instance as a parameter to the method. I get an empty output. Can anyone help out with this.

> if input is divisible by 3 output Fizz
> divisible by 5 output =  Buzz
> 3 & 5 = FizzBuz<

```
    private static string FizzBuzz<T>(T item)
    {
        int itemLength = item.ToString().Length;
        string output = "";

        if (itemLength % 3 == 0)
        {
            output += "Fizz";
        }
        if (itemLength % 5 == 0)
        {
            output += "Buzz";
        }

        return output;
    }
```

here is a class

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string  LastName { get; set; }
}
```

//in the main method class

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string result = (FizzBuzz("tests"));
    Console.WriteLine($"Tests: {result}");

    result = FizzBuzz(223);
    Console.WriteLine($"223:{result}");

    result = FizzBuzz ( new UserModel { FirstName = "Vic", LastName = "Okpas"});
    Console.WriteLine($" user model: {result}");
}
```

output:

```
Tests: Buzz
223: Fizz
user model:
```

the user model is supposed to output Fizz because the first name has 3 letters. Can anyone help me figure out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You need to learn how to debug your code: that will save you a lot of time. In this case, the first thing to do is to look at the output of `item.ToString()`, and see whether it is "user model" as you expect. You can do this using the debugger, or even a simple `Console.WriteLine`, for example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZfPurz). From that we can clearly see that `new UserModel().ToString()` returns "UserModel", and not the `FirstName` property

Comment: The reason for the empty string because a) you do not have a fallback option when the length is not divisible by 3 or 5, and b) you're not checking the FirstName property, you're checking the whole string result. Since `UserModel` does not override `ToString`, what you get is the full name of the type, something like `namespace.namespace.UserModel`.

Comment: Do note that this is a very odd interpretation of the FizzBuzz interview question, the normal interpretation is just to feed it numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is `ToString()` in `int itemLength = item.ToString().Length;`

Let's restructure your program a little bit to see what's happening.

```
static string FizzBuzz<T>(T item)
{
    int itemLength = item.ToString().Length;
    string output = "";

    if (itemLength % 3 == 0)
    {
        output += "Fizz";
    }
    if (itemLength % 5 == 0)
    {
        output += "Buzz";
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"'{item.ToString()}' -> {itemLength} -> '{output}'");
    return output;
}
```

Now the following code

```
FizzBuzz("tests");
FizzBuzz(223);
FizzBuzz(new UserModel
{
    FirstName = "Vic",
    LastName = "Okpas"
});
```

prints

```
'tests' -> 5 -> 'Buzz'
'223' -> 3 -> 'Fizz'
'UserModel' -> 9 -> 'Fizz'
```

The issue is that `ToString()` for a class gives its name.

With this knowledge, if you insist that your FizzBuzz should use `ToString().Length` as the number all we need to do teach the `ItemModel` class  how to return `FirstName` from `ToString()`:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName;
    }
}
```

Now the output for

```
FizzBuzz(new UserModel
{
    FirstName = "Vic",
    LastName = "Okpas"
});
```

is

```
'Vic' => 3 -> 'Fizz'
```

## Some notes

### A generic FizzBuzz?

FizzBuzz methods cannot really be made generic because their input really is a number and nothing else. What this number is for a given type is something that cannot be decided inside the method.

This is more sensible in my opinion:

```
static string FizzBuzz(int x)
{
    string output = "";
    if (x% 3 == 0)
    ...
}

// and then

var userModel = new UserModel
{
    FirstName = "Vic",
    LastName = "Okpas"
}

FizzBuzz(userModel.FirstName.Length);
```

## Interfaces

If you really wish to make you FizzBuzz more generic you could make it accept and interface.

```
static string FizzBuzz(IForFizzBuzz item)
{
    int x = item.NumberForFizzBuzz;
    string output = "";

    if (x % 3 == 0)
    {
        output += "Fizz";
    }
    if (x % 5 == 0)
    {
        output += "Buzz";
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"'{x} -> '{output}'");
    return output;
}

public class UserModel: IForFizzBuzz
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int NumberForFizzBuzz => FirstName.Length;
}

public interface IForFizzBuzz { 
    public int NumberForFizzBuzz {get; }

}
```

and then you can call it with your model

```
FizzBuzz(new UserModel
{
    FirstName = "Vic",
    LastName = "Okpas"
});
```

### Generic vs object

Since all types in C# provide `ToString()` your version of the method doesn't benefit from being generic and could just accept an `object`

```
static string FizzBuzz(object item)
{
    int itemLength = item.ToString().Length;
    string output = "";
...
```

Comment: This really worked out fine. Thanks